# Which are the best method to patch a gel saddle?

Tags: repair, gel-saddle

what are some ways to repair a gel saddle's hole?

This is my problem is on this one:

https://www.lidl.de/media/product/0/0/4/5/1/4/9/selle-royal-atb-trekking-sattel-show-gel-rio-mit-kantenschutz.jpg

A ~1cm² hole on the cover of the gel. I have tried taping it and using Shoe-Goo
but these two options fall off very quickly. any ideas?

I am hesitant of using superglue.

Comment: It will never look "right" so replacement is a fair and valid option.  If your saddle's damage was from new and you have the warranty and its under 24 months old, check the warranty FAQ at https://www.selleroyal.com/en/faq

Comment: well, it is older that that, so no warranty left... also, I just want to stop it from getting bigger and the gel from coming out. I also want it to last.

Answer (score 4):

A tight fitting lycra or spandex will cover the damage and can help prevent the hole from wearing larger.

It also gives you the opportunity to change up the look of your bike.
I've never had much luck trying to patch, glue or otherwise repair holes in a saddle.
[image]

Comment: thanx! it is an option...

Comment: Nice idea - I wonder if something that conforms under heat might work as a top-layer, like an offcut of car-wrapping vinyl ?

Comment: Wouldn't the cure become more expensive than the patient?

Comment: @Carel possibly, but like a comfortable pair of pants, its really hard to let go of something that fits you nicely.